# plot multiple plots with legends from other plots beside

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I have three plots `p1`, `p2` and `p3`.
I would like to combine `p2` and `p3` and add the legends of `p2` and `p1` on the right side above each other. In the following example the legends are identical. In the real data they are differend.

I use `ggplot2` and `cowplot`

```
# plot 1
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(alpha = .7) 


# plot 2
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(alpha = .7)

# plot 3
p3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(alpha = .7)


# legend1

legend1 <- get_legend(p1)

# legend2

legend2 <- get_legend(p2)

# combine plots
prow <- plot_grid( p2 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                   p3 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                   align = 'vh',

                   labels = c("a", "b"),

                   hjust = -1,

                   nrow = 1,
                   axis="1"

)

prow

# add legend1
p <- plot_grid( prow, legend1, rel_widths = c(1, .3))
p
# add legend2
plot_grid(p, legend2, rel_widths =c(1, .3))
```

This gives me this:
[image: Result]

What I try to get is:
[image: Wish]

I tried to solve the problem using

```
+ theme(legend.position=c()
```

and

```
+ theme(legend.justification = "top"))
```

however, I could not get the desired plot.

Comment: Why do you need two legends if they have the same information?

Comment: I assume the `iris` dataset was just used to illustrate the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually very close. You can use `ggdraw` to achieve what you want. See `?get_legend` for another example of this.

```
# combine plots
prow <- ggdraw(
  plot_grid(
    plot_grid(p2 + theme(legend.position="none") ,
               p3 +theme(legend.position="none"),
               align = 'vh',

               labels = c("a", "b"),

               hjust = -1,

               nrow = 1,
               axis="1"),
# as suggested by aosmith you can add additional columns to make legends appear closer
    plot_grid(legend1, legend2,ncol=4),
# I also set the relative widths so the legend takes up less space
nrow=1, rel_widths = c(1,0.2))
  )

prow
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the legends closer together (as in the OP's desired output example), you could add extra (empty) rows: `plot_grid(legend1, legend2, nrow = 4)`.  I didn't seem to need an extra `grid_draw` to make things work, but including the `rel_widths` code from the OP made the legend grid take up less space.

Comment: @aosmith yes there is too much white space on the right - I will update the answer to include the `rel_widths` parameter. Your suggestion to make the legends closer is also a good one